# Container command history logs

Tags: docker, containers

I need to get the container commands history on the host server. e.g I have used the kill -9   command inside the container and now the container is unable to start. From the host how can I get commands history inside the container on the host server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've been running manual commands like this inside a container and it's in an inconsistent state, the easiest way to recover is to delete the container and recreate it.  A container normally runs a _single_ process, and you shouldn't need debugging tools like `docker exec` to manage it.

Comment: Thanks, but here requirement is from the security team that there is the possibility that someone can do docker exec to container and do some unwanted stuff so they want to capture all commands run inside a container.